# How to sort a series of lines sharing the same vertex in clockwise order

Tags: sorting, computational-geometry, triangulation

I am trying to store a triangulation in a Doubly Connected Edge List structure, and I am stuck on one step.

**my question:** How can I sort a list of half-edges that all share the same tail in a clockwise order?

To those who aren't familiar with this data structure: How can I sort a list of lines all sharing one vertex in a clockwise order?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean clockwise relative to the vertex you really just want to sort them by their tangents. Assuming you have some way of referencing the points in the line this would look something like this in Python, since you haven't specified a specific language:

```
vertices = [[(1,2),(3,4)]...] # Some vertices assuming (1,2) is common vertex
sorting = lambda vector: math.atan(vector[1][1] / vector[1][0])
sorted_list = sorted(vertices, key=sorting)
```

There's also a reverse parameter if you want to switch to counter clockwise.

Comment: Could you please rewrite this in c++? I am a little confused about line 2 (since I don't know Python). Thank you!

Comment: @user2605344 The second line is just an arctangent.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. What is the arctangent going to help me with? Assuming I have v1, v2, and v3 where v1 is the common vertex, should I do atan(y3/y2) or atan(x3/x2) or what? I don't see how this is relevant mathematically. Thank you.

Comment: Never mind, I figured out a different way using determinants. I also understand your method now as well. Thank you.